# I am Getting an Error 401 message when accessing my site via HTTPS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, http-status-code-401, internet-connection

I am hosting a server from work, which has installed on it a Wordpress.org installation on localhost running through XAMPP with Apache and MySQL. I am now trying to install “really simple SSL” onto the Wordpress installation so its not an insecure site and that requires the site be loaded over https However, when i click to load over https i get a 401 authorization required error. Web dev is something new to me so i am requiring assistance and every instance of trying to access the site leads to the 401 error. If anyone is able to help that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Really Simple SSL plugin folder, than fix the siteurl in the WP_OPTION table by removing the HTTPS and leaving only http.

If you cannot set SSL on your local server it's better to stay with http than to wrongly set it.

Can be a problem if this site goes live, but for developing purpose it's not necessary.

By the way, for Windows systems I prefer Laragon to XAMPP.

Comment: This will be a server that the plan is it will be publicly accessible, that's why the lack of a https / SSL Cert is required. Inside PHPMYADMIN the test domain i am using uses http but when changed to https i can no longer access the site from any network locally or externally...

Comment: Maybe the 443 port is not under the NAT?